# Doing math on variables in blade, moving to controller

Tags: php, laravel

To clarify, this row appears properly on the webpage and shows the proper percentage, so this works perfectly. I'm just not crazy about doing this math directly in the blade for the div itself.

```
<div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ROUND((($snapshots[1]['COUNT'] - $snapshots[0]['COUNT']) / $snapshots[0]['COUNT'])*100,0)}}%</span></div>

I tried modifying it in the controller like so:

//this is the pre-existing variable where my data comes from
$snapshots = $callActivity->snapshot($this->slsno);

//this line was added for the percentage change
$percentChange = ($this->snapshots['CURRENT'] - $this->snapshots['PRIOR']) / $this->snapshots['PRIOR'];

//$snapshots was pre-existing, but I'm adding percentChange to the blade here
->with('snapshots', $snapshots)
->with('percentChange', $percentChange);
```

When I dump $percentChange here I get a NAN value, but if I just do the hardcoded html above it works perfectly. I'd just like to try and do this in the controller to keep the blade clean. What's the best way to do that here?

Comment: well, first step would be to dump `$this->snapshots` variable to confirm if it has the keys that is being used to calulate `$percentChange`

Comment: Yes, and they are being displayed elsewhere in the blade